# Waiting for ADF integration runtime http start call to complete in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-data-factory

I'm looking to start an Azure Data Factory SSIS Integration Runtime through my DevOps pipeline to allow a project deployment.

I have an agentless job with Invoke REST API to Start the runtime, set up as follows:

[image]

This works, however as the POST command is immediately succesful, the job stop also shows as successful.  What I want it to do is to wait until the runtime is actually started, much in the same way a Web Activity making this call would do in Data Factory.  I tried running Callback as a response, but that didn't seem to receive anything once the runtime had started (unless anyone is aware of a delay).

I would be grateful if anyone has any idea how to configure this to wait for completion? NB - I am already aware of how to do this in Azure PowerShell, I'm specifically looking REST API based answers.

Here is the JSON output from Data Factory and the output I'd be looking to poll:
[image]

Comment: Looks like Call Back may meet your needs, but it needs extra steps. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/http-rest-api?view=azure-devops#where-should-a-task-signal-completion-when-callback-is-chosen-as-the-completion-event).

Comment: Yeah, saw that before but obviously these are Azure REST APIs and I don't fancy me convincing Microsoft that they need to ping a callback back to DevOps. Sounds like one for their recommendations page which they'll get round to in 3 years' time....PowerShell it is.

Comment: There're only two available options of `Wait for completion`: `API response` and `CallBack`. If you choose api response, when that task executes the rest api, since the response is 200ok, it will show as successful immediately. As i know this is expected behavior in this situation.